# Ejabberd SASL external authentication for client SSL Authentication using certificates

Tags: ssl, ejabberd, sasl

So is there a module that supports SASL EXTERNAL for client SSL authentication using certificates in ejabberd. My search so far has resulted in dead links and forum discussions and also this http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0178.html. Wondering did someone implement this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This feature is not available in ejabberd Community Edition at the moment.

This is part of ejabberd Business offering.